# How to get the identity in asp.net MVC for Ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

Is there any way to get the identity in asp.net MVC during ajax calls.

Always HttpContext is coming null and .ASPXAUTH cookie also not sent to server.

Any working solutions or work arounds ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: don't know how to do, read few posts in stackoverflow but not clear

Comment: Please add some code so we can understand in the depth about your problem, what you have tried and what you need..?

Comment: Post your ajax call and the code that tries to get the identity.

Comment: Thanks for replying after lot of analysis, i found FormAuthentication Module was removed in web.config file. Since .net Framework uses identity 2.0.I removed that from web.config file it worked.